# Try to use tf.keras to learn the stocks and after learning 500 stocks, tf became very slow

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, tf.keras

I try to use `tensorflow.keras(CuRNNLSTM)` to compute the pattern of stocks. I use the following codes to compute about 500 stocks at the beginning of some month. And then store some good results in memory (predict each of the stocks in that month). Then the 2nd month I will again compute these 500 stocks and then do the daily predictions. And so on. I am using `tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1` and `GTX 1070`. From the 2nd months' learning, it became slower and slower. Especially the first epoch for every stock.

Is this because of the low efficiency of the GPU-memory reading data from memory of PC? What I can do about it?

I tried using code like the following to limit the taking-up of GPU-memory. But no use. It still becomes slower.

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
tf.enable_eager_execution(config=config)


for stock in df_all.minor_axis:
    print(stock)
    train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = handle_data(df_all[:, :-2, stock])

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/test999')

    filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models/{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc',
                                                          verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                                                          mode='max'))
    history = model.fit(train_x, train_y,
                        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                        epochs=EPOCHS,
                        validation_data=(train_x, train_y),
                        callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint])
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)
    if test_acc > 0.50:
        context.trade_stocks.append(stock)
        context.model_dict[stock] = model
        print('{}done!'.format(stock))


Epoch 1/10

  8/198 [>.............................] - ETA: 3:49 - loss: 0.9595 - acc: 0.2500
 24/198 [==>...........................] - ETA: 1:10 - loss: 0.9048 - acc: 0.5000
 40/198 [=====>........................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 0.8108 - acc: 0.5250
```

You can see after several months the first epoch of every stocks' learning became ridiculously slow.

Comment: I use LSTM and CuRNNLSTM on different PCs. The GPU version is much faster.

Comment: The data of each stock is first loaded in the memory. I can't figure out why putting data from memory into GPU would take so much time. I noticed it is gradually becoming slow.